# How do i display the Array List without [], and next lines instead of displaying on [1,2,3]

Tags: java, arrays, string, arraylist, split

Here is my code

```
 private List[] split(ArrayList aList) {

    ArrayList first = new ArrayList(); 
    ArrayList second = new ArrayList();

    int size = aList.size(); 

    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) 
             first.add(aList.get(i));

    for (int i = size / 2; i < size; i++) 
            second.add(aList.get(i));

    return new List[] { first, second };

}

Collections.shuffle(list);

List[] lists = split(list);     

jTextArea2.append(lists[0].toString());
jTextArea3.append(lists[1].toString());
```

This is how it looks like now... i want the list in Team A and Team B to be displayed list in Uploaded list

[image]

Comment: You need to loop over your lists and concatenate the elements in a String, instead of using toString

Answer (score 2):

Add each element separately:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lists[0].size(); i++) {
    jTextArea2.append(lists[0].get(i).toString());
    jTextArea2.append("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [joining collector](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining--) from [Streams api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html).

```
jTextArea2.append(lists[0].stream()
                      .map(Object::toString)
                      .collect(Collectors.joining("\n")));
```